# Apache POI HSSF : Reading Hyperlink address having number sign(#) from cell giving improper link address

Tags: apache-poi

## Step to reproduce issue:-

1. Create a xls file with one cell with a hyperlink.(Address of hyperlink should having number sign(#) in it. e.g "http://www.bailii.org/databases.html#uk")
2. Try to read address of hyperlink. It will give link address as "uk".Only characters after Address number sign (#) is considered as hyperlink address.

## Code snippet:-

String strLinkAddress = cell.getHyperlink().getAddress();

It will return "uk" as link address instead of "http://www.bailii.org/databases.html#uk"

Answer (score 0):

Use `cell.getHyperlink().getLabel()` instead.  You can check out the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/poi/3.8/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFHyperlink.java#HSSFHyperlink) here too see how POI handles the different kinds of hyperlinks which may be present in an .xls file.

**EDIT**

Ok, so if the label does not match the address, our job is harder.  That was a bit hackish of me.  So, if we examine the `HSSFHyperlink` class and view the different enumerations, something like `http://www.google.com` will be of type `LINK_URL` which is what we expect.  Something like `http://www.bailii.org/databases.html#uk` will resolve to type `LINK_DOCUMENT`.  But it's not a document, it's a URL!  Examining class `HyperlinkRecord`, I see the comment right before line 245:

`Text describing a place in document. In Excel UI, this is appended to the address, (after a '#' delimiter).  This field is optional. If present, the HLINK_PLACE must be set.`

The `HLINK_PLACE` makes `isDocumentLink` in line 699 of the same class return true thus classifying it as a document link, not a URL link.

Therefore, it appears as designed behaviour that whenever a # appears in a link, POI considers it to be a link within the document.  Don't know if I call that a bug, just it doesn't work like you might want it to.

Comment: cell.getHyperlink().getLabel() returns Label of Hyperlink not an address.
i want to get hyperlink address.